# how to get the apache spark job state and transfer it to front-end web in real-time?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to get the Apache job state or application state in real-time and push the state to front-end web for demonstration(web will show this state to users). How can I do this besides fetching information in json through visting RESTFUL API of spark? or any books can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past , i have used Apache LIVY.  There are REST API's available that allow you to submit spark jobs,  monitor status and report errors/completion
You can read more at : https://livy.incubator.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please check on `SparkUI`. I hope this will help you to get the spark state in Web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Getting spark job state depends on the way you are running your spark application.

So, if you ran your spark application on `yarn`, you can use `Yarn UI` and `Spark UI`

[image]

If you are running spark in Standalone for example, and as @Kumar Immanuel said, you can use `Spark UI`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You can use SparkLauncher and then SparkAppHandler to get the status
  of the job.
- You can also explore SparkListeners.